# Like placeholder text did not works perfectly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, firefox

I wanted to do like the following link:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RyanWalters/z9ymd852/)

When I tested in another browsers (chrome and IE), it works fine (the text is stick inside the textbox whenever I resizing the browser's screen).

But when it comes to the firefox, everything is messed up, so I used the CSS hacks only applied for firefox.

Everything works because I used media query and play with the position that only applied for firefox.

But, when it comes to the smaller screen (less than 768px), the text did not stick to left hand side, instead it is stick to the right hand side and following the screen size.

You can test it on the below link:

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/kAWqba1fE7#)

Here is the code itself:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row padding-row">
                <img class="img-responsive pull-left center-img" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/uiconstock/e-commerce/128/E-Commerce-Icon-Set-icon.png">
                <h2 class="text-center">My Website</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group input-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                <label class="control-label" for="txtUsername">Username</label>
                <input id="txtUsername" class="form-control" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group input-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
                <label class="control-label" for="txtPassword">Password</label>
                <input id="txtPassword" class="form-control" type="password">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <button id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-default form-control" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Submit">Log In</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* ---- REGION GENERAL ---- BEGIN */

body {
    background-color: #292929;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: white;
}

div[class*="col-"] {
    padding-right: 0px;
}

.input-group[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}

.input-group-addon {
    min-width: 40px;
}

.form-control {
    height: 40px;
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.control-label {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    opacity: .6;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3d(10px, 10px, 0px) scale(1);
    transform-origin: left top;
    transition: 300ms;
    z-index: 999;
    color: black;
}

.form-group.focused .control-label {
    transform: translate3d(10px, 0px, 0px) scale(.75);
    z-index: 998;
}

.popover-content {
    color: black;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .control-label {
        float: left;
        transform: translate3d(-225px, 10px, 0px) scale(1);
    }

    .form-group.focused .control-label {
        float: left;
        transform: translate3d(-225px, 0px, 0px) scale(.75);
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
        .control-label {
            margin-left: 50px;
        }

        .form-group.focused .control-label {
            margin-left: 50px;
        }
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
        .control-label {
            margin-left: -20px;
        }

        .form-group.focused .control-label {
            margin-left: -20px;
        }
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
        .control-label {
            margin-left: -90px;
        }

        .form-group.focused .control-label {
            margin-left: -90px;
        }
    }
}

/* ---- REGION GENERAL ---- END */

/* ---- REGION LOGIN PAGE ---- BEGIN */

.padding-row {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.center-img {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 383px) {
    .center-img {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
}

/* ---- REGION LOGIN PAGE ---- END */
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(window).resize(function () {
                $('.container').css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    left: ($(window).width() - $('.container').outerWidth()) / 2,
                    top: ($(window).height() - $('.container').outerHeight()) / 2
                });
            });

            $(window).resize();

            $('.form-control').on('focus blur', function (e) {
              $(this).parents('.form-group').toggleClass('focused', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value.length > 0));
                }).trigger('blur');
        })
```

Your answer much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since the css is acting different for browsers we should go browser specific.Add this to your css.

```
input:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* Firefox 18- */
input:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* Firefox 19+ */
```

Comment: Hi, because as from the example, they did not use placeholder to achieve the floating text, instead they used label and translate3d to achieve floating text. Is there anyway that I can use translate3d on the placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate placeholders just by using CSS. It would be best if you use the native placeholders instead of labels as a placeholder.

```
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder, 
    :-moz-placeholder,
    ::-moz-placeholder, 
    :-ms-input-placeholder {
        /* Styles */
    }
```

This will work in different browsers. And then just wrap it inside media queries for different screen sizes.

Also in transforms.

```
-webkit-transform:
-moz-transform: /* firefox */
-ms-transform:
-o-transform:
```

For example,

```
.control-label {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    opacity: .6;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3d(10px, 10px, 0px) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 10px, 0px) scale(1);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(10px, 10px, 0px) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(10px, 10px, 0px) scale(1);
    -o-transform: translate3d(10px, 10px, 0px) scale(1);
    transform-origin: left top;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
    -moz-transform-origin: left top;
    -ms-transform-origin: left top;
    -o-transform-origin: left top;
    transition: 300ms;
    z-index: 999;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: Hi, because as from the example, they did not use placeholder to achieve the floating text, instead they used label and translate3d to achieve floating text. Is there anyway that I can use translate3d on the placeholder?

Comment: what if you change the `@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)` to `@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)`

Comment: I edited my answer.

add all of that to the elements using transform.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I have tried your solution, but it didn't work also.